# How to overwrite the empty files in a directory?

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting.How to overwrite the empty files in a directory using shell scripting?
Can anyone help me above question...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty unspecific, please add tags and explain what scripting language you mean (eventually tell the OS you're using it).

With bash, you can overwrite files like this:

- With `mv`: `mv -f sourcefile /path/to/existing/destfile`
- With `cp`: `cp` overwrites files per default. To disable that behaviour, use the `-n` option

Comment: How to overwrite the empty files in a directory using shell scripting (Unix)

Answer (score 0):

If the files are really empty, I guess you overwrite them not for resetting the content, but change the times (atime, mtime ...)

If it is true, `touch` is the tool to use. `man touch` to learn the usage.

If you have a source file, you can just `cp or mv` as @weeheavy suggested.